# Unable to run Chatter api ios sample

Tags: ios5, restkit, restkit-0.20, salesforce-chatter

I am looking for some samples which I can use to post/retrieve feeds to/from groups in sales force chatter. While googling I have come across Chatter REST API in conjunction with RestKit. I was unable to run this sample which i have downloaded from github

https://github.com/cseymourSF/Chatter-API-iOS-Sample

After running the code i am able to login to sales force via application. But for the below
Request :

Sending asynchronous GET request to URL ///services/data/v23.0/chatter/users/userId.
(ex:///services/data/v23.0/chatter/users/me)

Error:

User fetch failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0xa58ffa0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=///services/data/v23.0/chatter/users/userId, NSErrorFailingURLKey=///services/data/v23.0/chatter/users/userId, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0xa5906d0 "unsupported URL"}

and the current url i am suing is below:

https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/chatter/users/me

any help could be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make your question specific. We won't help you find a library, that's what google is for. If you ask about your specific problem running the sample code you have then we can help with that.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for the quick reply. Still my question is not clearly please let me know

Comment: Describe what you did to get the sample, update it, run it. Show the code that crashes and give details of the crash type and message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like REST API wrong method invocation